# Como puedo verificar el tipo de objeto mediante pase de parametro? JAVA

Tags: java, poo, herencia

lo que quiero saber es si es posible saber el tipo de objeto mediante el paso de parametro, ejemplo:

```
private void add(object o) {
  if(o instanceof series) { 
    arraySeries.add(objeto);
  } else { 
    arrayVideo.add(objeto);
  } 
}
```

se que esto no se puede hacer ya que java no lo permite, pero si cambio el tipo de dato a series y lo valido tampoco me deja ingresarlo al `arrayVideo` ya que el tipo de dato no es de tipo `Video`, por eso queria saber si hay alguna manera de saber de que clase dicho objeto antes de ingresarlo a su respectivo array, sin necesidad de heredar.

Comment: Algunas dudas para poder ayudarte... ¿Por que el metodo recibe un tipo Object? ¿De que tipo de datos es arraySeries? ¿De que tipo de dato es arrayVideo? ¿Estás usando herencia?

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que:

- `series` Se trata de un tipo de dato.
- `arraySeries` es una `Collection` y se ha declarado más o menos así `Collection<series> arraySeries;` (e inicializado, por supuesto)
- `arrayVideo` es una `Collection` y se ha declarado más o menos así `Collection<Video> arrayVideo;` (e inicializado, por supuesto)

Lo único que tienes que hacer es un casting al objeto `o`, ya que la variable `objeto` no existe, en dependencia del resultado del `intanceof`.

```
private void add(object o) {
    if(o instanceof series) { 
        arraySeries.add((series) o);
    } else { 
        arrayVideo.add((Video) o);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es que una vez pasado a `Object` ya no hay forma de saber de que tipo (Video o Series) era. Por lo que no te va a servir pasarlo a `Object`. Lo que podes hacer es usar genéricos. Investigá un poco sobre programación genérica